# Cakephp 3 and Authentication

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.0

Is there an easy way like in Cakephp 3 to work with roles

APP Controller

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    // Admin can access every action
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}
```

POSTS Contoller

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // All registered users can add posts
    if ($this->action === 'edit') {
        return true;
    }

    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

I know from http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#testing-actions-protected-by-authcomponent that

```
$this->auth->deny('add');
```

Is doing it, but how can I add the user/admin ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to achieve? MAybe admin routing is what you want http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#Cake\Routing\Router::prefix

Comment: I want to restrict access for users with the role author. They shouldn´t Delete Posts nor should the view/delete/add users.

Comment: than you would need something like this in your isAuthorized method `if ($this->action == "add" && $user->role == "author") { return false; }`

Comment: You can use prefix routing https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html  as @rrd said, and you can use beforeFilter() method of app controller to check for prefix and the actions allowed for the user with auth component.

Answer (score 0):

I have used ACL authentication in very simple way with isAuthorised() method. I hope it would be help you.

AppController.php
you can make have to define property

```
/**
 * ACCESS CONTROL LIST BASED ON METHODS OF CLASS FOR USER ROLES
 */
var $accessControllList = array();
```

Define private method

```
private function _checkAccessControll() {
    if ($this->Auth->user('id')) {
        if (!isset($this->accessControllList) || empty($this->accessControllList)) {
            return true;
        }

        $action_name = $this->request->params['action'];
        $user_role = $this->Auth->user('role');
        if (isset($this->accessControllList['allowed']) && !empty($this->accessControllList['allowed']) && in_array($action_name, $this->accessControllList['allowed'])) {
            return true;
        } else if (isset($this->accessControllList['role_base'][$user_role]) && !empty($this->accessControllList['role_base'][$user_role]) && in_array($action_name, $this->accessControllList['role_base'][$user_role])) {
            return true;
        }

        throw new \Cake\Network\Exception\ForbiddenException(__('You not have access for this page'));
    }
    return true;
}
```

in isAuthorized() add below line.

```
$this->_checkAccessControll();
```

In any controller, you need to mapping your ACL with roles. For you PostsController.php file something as below

```
/**
 * List of all accessible Action from URL
* @var array
*/
var $accessControllList = array(
    'allowed' => array('view','index'), // allowed for any role.
    'role_base' => array(
        'administrator' => array('delete', 'approve'), //specially allowed for administrator only
        'publisher' => array('view','create','index','replyComment'), // specially allowed for publisher only
        'reader' => array('postComment','replyComment') // specially allowed for reader
    )
);
```